# Optimize MySQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a database that stores products. The two biggest tables are my products table and images table.
Products: ~19.000 rows

Images: ~34.000 rows

Categories: ~60 rows

Raw categories: ~1200 rows

Brands: 700 rows

(The other tables are only a couple of rows)

I also have a table with brands, raw categories, static categories (the raw categories are mapped to a static category).

I have created a Product VIEW to gather the data I need, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `jos_clothes_view_products` AS
SELECT tbl.*, r.name AS reseller, b.name AS brand, rcat.raw_name AS cats_raw, cats1.name AS cat1, cats1.slug AS catslug1, cats2.name AS cat2, cats2.slug AS catslug2
FROM `jos_clothes_products` AS tbl
LEFT JOIN `jos_clothes_brands` AS b ON b.clothes_brand_id = tbl.clothes_brand_id
LEFT JOIN `jos_clothes_resellers` AS r ON r.clothes_reseller_id = tbl.clothes_reseller_id
LEFT JOIN `jos_clothes_catraws` AS rcat ON rcat.clothes_catraw_id = tbl.clothes_catraw_id
LEFT JOIN `jos_clothes_categories` AS cats2 ON cats2.clothes_category_id = rcat.clothes_category_id
LEFT JOIN `jos_clothes_categories` AS cats1 ON cats1.clothes_category_id = cats2.parent_id
```

Then when running a query like this from PHP:

```
SELECT `tbl`.* FROM `jos_clothes_view_products` AS `tbl` WHERE  `tbl`.`cat1` != 'NULL' AND `tbl`.`enabled` = '1' ORDER BY `created_on` DESC , `ordering` ASC LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

The query is often very slow! Not always though (probably because of caching?). I have also noticed that it creates a tmp-table at about 200MB in size. Sometimes it gets even bigger and fails with "Invalid key for file....".

Any ideas how I can optimize the query? Or the VIEW actually, I guess it's the bottleneck here. Correct?

Product table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_clothes_products` (
  `clothes_product_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `clothes_reseller_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `aff_prod_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `clothes_brand_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `clothes_catraw_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `shipping_cost` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `currency` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `availibility` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `product_url` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `real_url` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `access` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ordering` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `modified_on` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `locked_on` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `locked_by` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`clothes_product_id`),
  KEY `clothes_brand_id` (`clothes_brand_id`),
  KEY `clothes_catraw_id` (`clothes_catraw_id`),
  KEY `created_on` (`created_on`),
  KEY `clothes_reseller_id` (`clothes_reseller_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18962 ;
```

Any ideas?

Best Regards

EDIT: Structure of jos_clothes_catraws

```
--
-- Struktur för tabell `jos_clothes_catraws`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_clothes_catraws` (
  `clothes_catraw_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `clothes_category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `clothes_reseller_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `raw_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`clothes_catraw_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1289 ;
```

Comment: Have you tried an EXPLAIN on the statement? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html Also check the related questions for this as these sort of questions have been answered a lot of times. I would also suggest using MERGE tables for massive tables.

Comment: Have you indexed all the *_id columns?

Comment: 19,000 product rows currently, and yet you have choosen to use a bigint for the auto-inc key (and your other FK keys) ?

Comment: @Paul Schreiber Yes, they are indexed. @Mitch Wheat A little optimistic maybe? ;) I have changed that to int(11) instead. Still the same issues though. @Rasika Yes I have. I don't really know how to read the info in the EXPLAIN though... Here's the output: http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/378/skrmavbild20110309kl015.png

Comment: How long does the query take to run?

Comment: Most of the time it takes like 1s. But that has to be when it's cached or something. Then sometimes it takes more than 40 seconds and it writes over 200MB to a tmp table file on disk. The query gets logged in my slow query with this info: "# Query_time: 40  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 20  Rows_examined: 79492 ...." Weird that it examines almost 80k rows?

Comment: Can you check whether your jos_clothes_catraws has a key for clothes_catraw_id as this is the one using the temp table and not using any indexes for the join as per EXPLAIN output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your EXPLAIN output, it looks like the culprit is the `jos_clothes_catraws` table which is not using any indexes to do the join. This is the one generating the large temp table. First check whether the table has a key for `clothes_catraw_id`.

You could also use [USE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) syntax to force the use of the index or do an [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html) on the table to make sure that the table statistics are updated so that the temp table is avoided.

Another point that I can see is the mix of ascending and descending order in the query you use in PHP. Try using a descending order key for the created_on field and preferably a combined key for the two fields.

Also try running the query directly instead of through the view as there are mentions in the MySQL [Restrictions on Views section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-restrictions.html) that some views may not use indexes although the actual statement could use the indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! No luck yet though. The `clothes_catraw_id`field is my PRIMARY key in the `jos_clothes_catraws` table so it's a key. I don't get why it won't use it! I even tried with USE INDEX(PRIMARY) and FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) but it doesn't seem to care about that... I also tried running the query directly but it seems to be the same thing.

Comment: I have edited my first post with the structure of jos_clothes_catraws

Comment: @Linus, have you tried the other options of running the query directly (without the view), using the bi-directional index (desc created_on and asc ordering) and using Index hints?